# numpy.zeros shape statement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I have came across this statement in Python:

```
np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
```

I understood that this aims at creating an array filled with zeros from [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), but couldn't understand this part `1 + X.shape[1]`.

I tried running a small test like this:

```
import numpy as np
X = [[1,2],[3,4]]
m = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
print m
```

But, got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    m = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Why is that? How can we read the above statement?

Thanks.

Comment: `x` should be a numpy array, not a list.

Comment: You need to make X a numpy array, not a list, if you want to access its shape.  Try `X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List doesn't have `shape` property. You should use `np.array` to get the shape.

Try this

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
m = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
print m
```

To make it a numpy array you should do this `X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` this will be a numpy array.

And `X.shape` will return `(2,2)` and `X.shape[1]` will return `2`.

So `1 + x.shape[1]` will return `3` and `m = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])` `m` will have a value like this `array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])`